# Bootstrap 4 container class leavse a strange dot beside the container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 container class to align my project details according to screen resolution size.

But the use of "container" class leaves a strange dot which I am unable to remove.

Here is the code of the HTML page I am working on - [index.html](https://github.com/nilutpolkashyap/nilutpolkashyap.github.io/blob/master/index.html)

The website is deployed live at https://nilutpolkashyap.github.io/ . You can see the unwanted "dot" live in the website

[Image showing the unwanted dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfsQ1.png)

**Solutions tried**
I couldn't figure out a solution to fix it. Removing the "container" class doesn't help with my whole purpose.

Comment: Use your browser devtools to see exactly what/where is creating that dot. You'll soon see it's the after pseudo element on the .container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your [.css file](https://github.com/nilutpolkashyap/nilutpolkashyap.github.io/blob/master/styles.css#L613), you have the class `.container::after`, that makes those "circles on the timeline", if you remove they disapear.

Comment: Thanks a lot @francisco It solved my problem in removing the unwanted dot